# Cypher: merge path without duplicate relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am currently implementing a graph database in which persons are allocated to projects (of a customer) using an allocation node. Customers or Projects may or may not exist already, the Allocation node should be unique (each Allocation node can only have one incoming and one outgoing relationship). The code below works, but duplicates the Project->Customer relationship when both already exists in the database. How can I prevent this?

```
MATCH (p:Person {id:1})
MERGE (c:Customer {id:1})
MERGE (pr:Project {id:1})
CREATE (p)-[:HAS_ALLOCATION]->(a:Allocation)-[:ON_PROJECT]->(pr)-[:HAS_CUSTOMER]->(c)
RETURN a,p,pr,c;
```

[image: a busy cat]

Answer (score 0):

You should try both `MERGE` and `CREATE UNIQUE` in place of your `CREATE` clause and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: I tried that before, and got `The pattern (p)-[109:HAS_ALLOCATION]->(a) produced multiple possible paths, and that is not allowed`

Comment: Was that `MERGE`, `CREATE UNIQUE`, or both?

Comment: You might also try doing it one relationship at a time (I'm kindof guessing here ;)